# Multiple IPsec tunnels implented with raccon - need tunnel specific debug output

Tags: vpn, logging, ipsec

I have a network appliance box serving as an end point for several site to site IPsec VPN tunnels. raccon's docs specify that a log file can be written to with the -l option. My clunky approach to segregate log info into tunnel specific files is just to spawn multiple raccon processes on boot with the -f and -l option set for each specifying the particular tunnel config and log output.

Before I try that out on production, does anyone have a clean and neat log structure for individual IPsec tunnels? I can parse the main log file for textual identifying strings, but I deem that a sub-optimal solution.